# 2D Game development in C++ tutorial

Tags: c++

Terry Cavanaugh reccomended I learn C++ the other day, so can somebody link me to a complete and recent(late 2012 at the oldest), game development tutorial? I would prefer just C++, but, if you don't know one, an external library would be okay.
   I can make games in C#/Python/Java, so I know the very basics(like what an int is), but I have tried to use C++ and noticed a vast difference in the syntax of the language, and so far I have been unable to find a decent tutorial on YouTube. Can someone please point me towards a       good windows friendly 2d game development tutorial in C++ tutorial.

Comment: It probably is operating system dependent. You might consider [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/)

Answer (score 3):

1.) Start out by just learning some C++ and getting comfortable with the language. I recommend thenewboston:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvC1WCdV1XU&list=PLAE85DE8440AA6B83

2.) Then you can move on to learning game libraries such as Allegro, SDL, OpenGL, etc.

This site has some good Allegro tutorials:

http://www.cppgameprogramming.com/cgi/nav.cgi?page=allegbasics

And some good OpenGL and SDL tutorials:

http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn C++ with general tutorials. For making games, I recommend

http://www.packtpub.com/sfml-game-development/book